# openni_params missing

Tags: calibration, turtlebot, ubuntu, ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm in the process of upgrading a Turtlebot from Ubuntu 11.04/Electric to 12.04/Fuerte.  The first thing to do is to recalibrate, but when I run turtlebot_calibration I'm getting the following:

```
error loading <rosparam> tag: 
    file does not exist [/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/openni_camera/info/openni_params.yaml]
XML is <rosparam command="load" file="$(find openni_camera)/info/openni_params.yaml"/>
```

Indeed it does appear that the openni_params file is missing.  What happened to this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35531/openni_params-missing/) by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on ROS Answers with karma: 995 on 2012-06-03

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just experienced the same problem migrating my robot setup to Fuerte. It looks like the old openni_camera package got split up and deprecated. There is a [migration guide](http://ros.org/wiki/openni_camera_deprecated#Migration_guide), and you should be able to modify the turtlebot_calibration source accordingly until an official Fuerte version is released.

---

Originally posted by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) with karma: 2871 on 2012-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SivamPillai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2018/sivampillai/) on 2012-07-24**:
I did not well understand the migration guide. should I obtain the deprecated version first and change my dependency names or depend upon the new openni package? I have the same problem as asked above.

**Comment by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on 2012-07-25**:
I would recommend depending on the new openni package. It also seems a turtlebot stack has been released for Fuerte. You might want to try it out.

**Comment by [SivamPillai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2018/sivampillai/) on 2012-07-25**:
I'm sorry but I have a different Robot... its Husky A200 :)